# Understanding 'parentNode' of undefined error

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing basic JS skills by setting up little exercises for myself. In this one, I have a list of `<a>`s inside a div. The aim of the exercise is to wrap each `<a>` in a div. I'm using `replaceChild` in this instance.

Oddly (to me at least) the script works for the first three links, but after that throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

I can't tell why the script partly works. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Here's the code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
div div {padding: 10px; background: #e7e7e7; margin: 5px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
</div>

<script>
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0, ii=links.length; i<ii; i++) 
{
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    links[i].parentNode.replaceChild(container, links[i]);
    container.appendChild(links[i]);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's an online version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lpuky

I've tried the few debugging techniques that I know of and read about this error message, but haven't worked out what's wrong here. Seems funny to me that it works for 3 of the 6 links.

Comment: Quick tip: `for( var i = links.length-1; i>=0; i--)` avoids the problem. Working backwards is usually a good idea when working with nodes.

Comment: Yep, good point. That came up in the comments below, too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying the nodelist as you iterate over it.  Use the Array slice method to make a copy of the list:

```
var linksCopy = Array.prototype.slice.call(links);
for (var i=0; i<linksCopy.length; i++) 
{
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    linksCopy[i].parentNode.replaceChild(container, linksCopy[i]);
    container.appendChild(linksCopy[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the answer. This works nicely. Looks pretty sophisticated, though. I look forward to learning more about `prototype` etc. Out of interest, is there a simpler option? (That's not a criticism, mind you, I'm just enjoying the learning process here.)

Comment: @ralph.m Yeah, this is a little unnecessary. Just loop backwards (from the collection length minus 1, to 0).

Comment: Thanks Ian. I'm so hopelessly new at this that I'm not quite sure how to do that. Would this just involve modifying the `for` loop to decrement, or does that run into the same problem?

Comment: @ralph.m No, that's exactly what you'd do. You'd use: `for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { }`

Comment: Thanks Ian. Unless I'm missing something, that seems to have a similar issue as with my original. The first `<a>` in the loop doesn't get inserted into the new div because it doesn't exist any more, and the script stops ... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Be darned, so it does. The difference in your code from mine is the addition of `var link = links[i];`. I'm not sure why just using `links[i]` makes a difference, but your approach is better anyhow. Thanks very much for the follow up. Much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The collection `links` is `NodeList` and is *live*.

Since you are replacing them, they are disappearing from the collection and our index into them is no longer pointing to anything.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to this, I often hear that `querySelectorAll()` is different in that it returns a static Nodelist rather than an array, so I thought that might come in handy here, and indeed it does:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
div div {padding: 10px; background: #e7e7e7; margin: 5px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
</div>

<script>
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i=0, ii=links.length; i<ii; i++) 
{
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    links[i].parentNode.replaceChild(container, links[i]);
    container.appendChild(links[i]);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, an alternative to `Array.prototype.slice.call(links)` is `[].slice.call(links)`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
div div {padding: 10px; background: #e7e7e7; margin: 5px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
</div>

<script>
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var linksCopy = [].slice.call(links);
for (var i=0; i<linksCopy.length; i++) 
{
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    linksCopy[i].parentNode.replaceChild(container, linksCopy[i]);
    container.appendChild(linksCopy[i]);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And another option again is to use `[].forEach.call()`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
div div {padding: 10px; background: #e7e7e7; margin: 5px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
</div>

<script>
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(el) {
var container = document.createElement("div");
el.parentNode.replaceChild(container, el);
container.appendChild(el);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Yet another option, using Array.from():

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
div div {padding: 10px; background: #e7e7e7; margin: 5px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
    <a href="">link</a>
</div>

<script>
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var linksCopy = Array.from(links);
for (var i=0; i<linksCopy.length; i++)
{
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    linksCopy[i].parentNode.replaceChild(container, linksCopy[i]);
    container.appendChild(linksCopy[i]);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your own follow-up answer: if your objective was simply to find the easiest way to wrap the `<a>`s in `<div>`s, rather than to practice with `createElement`, `replaceChild` or `appendChild` or any of the other methods, this would be it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
<style>
div div {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <a href="#">link</a>
        <a href="#">link</a>
        <a href="#">link</a>
        <a href="#">link</a>
        <a href="#">link</a>
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>

<script>
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].outerHTML = '<div>'+links[i].outerHTML+'</div>';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

.
Live demo here: http://jsbin.com/jasoho/1/edit?html,output. Another advantage of the `outerHTML` method is that it doesn't change the `nodeList`. So you can also use `getElementsByTagName` in stead of `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Sorry I missed this answer when you posted it. Nice work. :-)